# Wordpress - URL rewriting for static pages

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, wordpress-theming

I want to change the URL of my static contact page on a WordPress v3.8 website.
Here is the code I am using from my theme's `function.php` file:

```
function ebi_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_action( 'init', 'flush_rewrite_rules');
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'additional_rewrite_rules');

function additional_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite) {
    $new_rules = array(  
        'contact?' => 'index.php?page_id=22'  
    );  
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;  
}
```

When trying to access www.mysite.com/contact I get:

> The requested URL /baoene/contact was not found on this server.

Any idea why the URL rewriting is not working properly?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just define it as the permalink?

Comment: Hmmm... I am confused. 
How could I define it as the permalink (first site on Wordpress)

Comment: Assuming it's a static page added within Wordpress, there's a permalink option below the title on the edit page.

Comment: Sure, but I can't edit it. Would you know why?
All I can do is choosing beteen the difference permalink schemes in the "Settings" tab

Comment: Is there no edit button?

Comment: Nop, only a redirection to `Settings > Permalinks`

Comment: Do you have permalinks set up?

Comment: Hmmm... I resolved my issue. 
Thank you very much. You got me into investigating further the Permalinks. That is how I got it solved. 

I'll post a reply to explain

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. The code sample above IS correct. 
The problem was I had no `.htaccess` file at the root of my WordPress website. Thus, URL mod_rewrite wasn't used.

1. I added a `.htaccess` file to the root
2. I gave apache write access to the file, so WordPress could update it automatically
3. I modified my `httpd.conf` to allow `.htaccess` directive like this:

```
   Directory /var/www/html/mysite>
    AllowOverride All
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    /Directory>
```

I hope this helps